# VirusTotal Api unclear usage

Tags: php, api

I scan files from folder ($cfile has fake content intentionally)

```
$api_key = getenv('VT_API_KEY') ? getenv('VT_API_KEY') :$this->_key;
$cfile = 'asdasdas';

$post = array('apikey' => $api_key,'file'=> $cfile);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // remove this if your not debugging
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); // please compress data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "gzip, My php curl client");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$result=curl_exec ($ch);
```

And get fine result with something like :

```
stdClass Object
(
[scan_id] => ffd8f48291484e1373573bfedf591cdf38565fcc9fc89a4a1d0f16a98da4d4ec-1573916013
[sha1] => d8cc708a1760020e00e1da0e83dc1f7b25e5a5ab
[resource] => ffd8f48291484e1373573bfedf591cdf38565fcc9fc89a4a1d0f16a98da4d4ec
[response_code] => 1
[sha256] => ffd8f48291484e1373573bfedf591cdf38565fcc9fc89a4a1d0f16a98da4d4ec
[permalink] => https://www.virustotal.com/file/ffd8f48291484e1373573bfedf591cdf38565fcc9fc89a4a1d0f16a98da4d4ec/analysis/1573916013/
[md5] => 7ae6fa4e9595a6e9d7987b4cd66f5b7f
[verbose_msg] => Scan request successfully queued, come back later for the report
 )
```

Why do I set file wrong and have good result ?

Comment: Please try to avoid using swear words in your question. I've edited to remove it

Comment: So what exactly is the _question_ here? Anything unclear about what “Scan request successfully queued, come back later for the report” means?

Comment: @04FS, look at `$cfile` and read post one more time. At the end I see some question. Do you see it too?

Comment: Why would you try and send a file you know doesn’t exist? And why would you need to get a response from an external API telling you that?

Comment: why does it scan file which does not exist??? and give me scan_id ??

Comment: Probably because they simply put _every_ incoming request in a queue first, without doing much validation on it at that point.

Comment: what can you recommend as an anti-virus with an API other than VirusTotal?